# Passing variables to text javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

Im trying to pass 3 variables to one main variable and then put it into text the part of the code that doesn't work is text: "+won+", does anyone know how to fix this part? little extra so you can understand what im doing ...all the vars will be displayed as text in a div called quote.

```
var w = "W";
var o = "o";
var n = "n";

var won1 = w + o + n;


(function() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "+won+",
          img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
        },
        {
          text: "+won+",
          img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
        }

      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
       '<center>' + '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">' + '</center>';
    })();
```

whats happening:
what is happening is it isnt getting vars for example if i put +won1+ it displays the text "+won1+" instead of the variables which read "won"
Many thanks for reading :)

Comment: Try `text: won` instead of `text: "+won+"`.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag on your question? And FYI, the `<center>` element doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What is happening, and what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Im trying to what it says in the title and what is shows in the code what is happening is it isnt getting vars for exaple if i put +won1+ it displays the text "+won1+" instead of the varables which read "won"

Comment: What are you expecting when you put `+won1+`? As Oriol says, have you tried `won,`?

Comment: I've changed the var won to won1 so i can see if its changed and no just won doesn't work, Im expecting the word "won" to show after the code reads and puts the vars together.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uxr2Lr87/?

Comment: No idea why its not working on my server but yeah its working in jsfiddle odd and yes like that

Comment: @user3112634, may be because it was fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```js
var w = "W";
    var o = "o";
    var n = "n";

    var won = w + o + n;


    (function() {
          var quotes = [
            {
              text: won,// if you want to get displayed text as won1 use,text:won+1,
              img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
            },
            {
              text: won,
              img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
            }

          ];
          var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
          console.log(quote);
          document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
           '<center>' + '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
            '<img src="' + quote.img + '">' + '</center>';
        })();
```

```html
<p type="text" id="quote" value="Test value"></p>
```

Comment: @user3112634 try this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var w = "W";
var o = "o";
var n = "n";

var won1 = w + o + n;


(function() {
  var quotes = [{
      text: won1,
      img: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
    }, {
      text: won1,
      img: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
    }

  ];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<center>' + '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
    '<img src="' + quote.img + '">' + '</center>';
})();
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
```